# Google Place autocomplete status 9000

Tags: android, google-places-api

I was trying to get places prediction using the Places Autocomplete API from Google Play Services. It worked absolutely fine before I tested with signed apk. Running the signed apk and trying to get the places prediction, I am getting this

Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 9001, resolution=null}
Any Idea's what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue here is that the key you're using doesn't have the SHA1 fingerprint of your app's release certificate whitelisted. Try following the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup#find-cert) to retrieve the fingerprint corresponding to your release certificate. You can then add it to your Android Key in the Google Developers Console.

We're working on improving the error message in this scenario - apologies for the inconvenience!

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Instructions link is not there. Please share.

Comment: Whoops, fixed it now.